# Map specific values from other df

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df1`:

```
   T1 T2  
0  H  A     
1  D  H
```

And `df2`:

```
   Rank  H    D    A
0  M1   0.2  0.4  0.4   
1  M2   0.5  0.4  0.1
```

I want to add 2 columns to df1 with values picked from df2.

- If T1 = H then i pick the H-value from M1
- If T2 = A then i pick A-value from M2

Desired output:

```
   T1 T2  M1   M2  
0  H  A  0.2  0.1
1  D  H  0.4  0.5
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, yes!! You can achieve what you want by using the `map` method using your own dataframe as key-value pairs (as a dictionary).

```
df1_to_df2 = {'T1': 'M1', 'T2': 'M2'}  # Maps col from df1 to row in df2
my_map = df2.set_index('Rank').T.to_dict()  # Maps cols from df2 to their values

for col in df1.columns:
    new_col = df1_to_df2[col]
    df1[new_col] = df1[col].map(my_map[new_col])
```

Then you get the following dataframe for `df1`

```
  T1 T2   M1   M2
0  H  A  0.2  0.1
1  D  H  0.4  0.5
```

Let us know if you have any further issues!